# Recursive module import and reload

Tags: python, reload, python-import

Can someone explain why executing the following code:

file "**hello.py**":

```
import hello
print "hello"
hello = reload(hello)
```

executing as `python hello.py` prints the following?

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Why 4 times? I know that when a module is already imported it's not imported again, but reload forces to reload a module even if it's already loaded. I'd have expected as a result unlimit 'hello' prints.

What has to happen so `reload` won't reload a module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`python hello.py` (A) runs the code once, when (A) calls `import hello` the code is run again (B), when (A) and (B) call `reload(hello)`, the code is run twice more, for four times total.

In general, for the lifetime of a program a module's code will be executed at the following times:

- Once if it is the main module
- When it is imported the **first** time by any module (including itself)
- Any time `reload()` is called on the module

As for why the `reload()` is not called recursively, there is an early exit point to the PyImport_ReloadModule() function (CPython, file is import.c) to prevent this:

http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/import.c?view=markup#l2646

```
    ...
    existing_m = PyDict_GetItemString(modules_reloading, name);
    if (existing_m != NULL) {
        /* Due to a recursive reload, this module is already
           being reloaded. */
        Py_INCREF(existing_m);
        return existing_m;
    }
    ... load module code is below here
```

Comment: but I want to know why do reload isn't called again when the module is being reloaded. And if there are any more reasons which would make it not reload

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the reloads within reloads don't run the code again.

Comment: Just tracked down the CPython source code for why the reloads within reloads do not occur.

Comment: If memory serves you used to be able to segfault Python by doing this.  Good times, good times..

Answer (score 8):

`reload` keeps a list (actually a dict) of modules it is currently reloading to avoid reloading modules recursively.

See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e6b8202443b6/Lib/imp.py#l236

This isn't documented, as such, but I think you can probably rely on it remaining the case.